# Can I filter a Matrix or Vector with a string sentence in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array, filter

I'm implementing a Google Script WebApp which will be able to filter a Google Sheet with a few parameters. What is happening is... I have a 30 columns approximately and each column would be a parameter. I thought this:

```
let MYBOOK = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
let SS = MICBOOK.getSheetByName('DATA');
let DATA = SS.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
let f = null;

if(e.nombre != ''){  // Never null
  f += 'index[0] == e.nombre'
}

if(e.ciudad != ''){
  f += '&& index[1] == e.ciudad '
}

if(e.tipo != ''){
  f += '&& index[2] == e.tipo '
}

let result = DATA.filter(index => {
  return f;
})

// And more and more if ...

return result;
```

But the script result is all matrix and no filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a solution and i found a similar question. All i need was

```
eval(string);
```

To convert a string to a Js Code, so if a put:

```
data.filter(index => {
  return eval(f);
})
```

Where `f = index[0] == e.nombre && index[1] == e.ciudad && index[2] == e.tipo` it returns a new Matrix with filters values OK.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
let MYBOOK = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
let SS = MICBOOK.getSheetByName('DATA');
let DATA = SS.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
let f = null;


let result = DATA.filter(datum => {

// moved if statements inside this function

  if(datum.nombre != ''){  // Never null
    f += 'index[0] == e.nombre'
  }

  if(datum.ciudad != ''){
    f += '&& index[1] == e.ciudad '
  }

  if(datum.tipo != ''){
    f += '&& index[2] == e.tipo '
  }



  return f;
})

// And more and more if ...

return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that. The f string was: index[0] == e.nombre && index[1] == e.ciudad && index[2] == e.tipo

But the filter function return all registers with no filter data.